# Edge overlapping an icon inside of a button

Tags: html, css

I want set the icon in the edge of button, so that a half part is inside and another part is outside of the button. I tried several things, but this one is currently the best result, but still the `overlapping-effect` doesn't work outside of the button.

I have created a codepen for this issue - [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/bronxy1337/pen/NWPEwrp).

Here you can see, that the icon is not "visible" outside of the button. 
[image]

**CSS CODE**

```
.topleft-icon
{
  position: absolute;
  right: -8px;
  top: -8px;
}

.bewertungButtonStyle
{
  margin: 0 !important;
  min-width: 50px; 
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div style="padding: 200px; background: gray">
    <tr style="background-color: #FAFAFA">
        <td class="td_rasterGridStyle">
            <ion-button class="bewertungButtonStyle">
                <ion-icon class="topleft-icon" name="checkmark-circle"></ion-icon>
                1 </ion-button>
        </td>

        <td class="td_rasterGridStyle">

            <ion-button class="bewertungButtonStyle">
                <ion-icon class="topleft-icon" name="checkmark-circle"></ion-icon>
                1 </ion-button>
        </td>

        <td class="td_rasterGridStyle">
            <ion-button class="bewertungButtonStyle">
                <ion-icon class="topleft-icon" name="checkmark-circle"></ion-icon>
                1 </ion-button>
        </td>

        <td class="td_rasterGridStyle">

            <ion-button class="bewertungButtonStyle">
                <ion-icon class="topleft-icon" name="checkmark-circle"></ion-icon>
                1 </ion-button>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <div>
```

Comment: Why you use a table for a layout?

Comment: If you remove the "contain" property and set the overflow to visible at the class button you have your wished result.

Comment: @Luke where I have used the contain property? :O

Comment: @Sfili_81 in the entire context, I have to use a table, but it's not actually the problem.

Comment: No it's not the problem, but using table for layout it's not a good idea.

Comment: @CallMeBronxy inspect the button-tag and in the description for ".button" on the last position is "contain: content"
If you remove this and the overflow you have the result